# Is it possible to get the deleted/removed character on backspace in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to know the deleted character on backspace in unity. I need to check the particular end character of the string.

`e.g. abcd<quad material =0 size => 89 >`

If the string ends with '>' - checks for the condition, and will do some operations based on this.

This check is happening on backspace but, on pressing backspace, the '>' gets deleted and this condition remains false always. So, is there any way I can know the deleted character on backspace.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about an `UI.InputField` you could probably use [`onValidateInput`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValidateInput.html) and check if the input was a backspace char (`\b`).

Maybe something like e.g.

```c#
[SerializeField] private InputField _inputField;

private void Awake ()
{
    if(!_inputField) _inputField = GetComponent<InputField>();

    _inputField.onValidateInput += CheckInput;
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    _inputField.onValidateInput -= CheckInput;
}

private char CheckInput(char charToValidate)
{
    if (charToValidate == '\b')
    {
        var lastChar = _inputField.text[_inputField.text.Length - 1];
        //ToDo Do something with lastChar         
    }

    return charToValidate;
}
```

`onValidateInput` as far as I remember is executed before the character is actually added to the input, thus before e.g. `onValueChanged` is called.

---

As alternative you could of course also simply store the last value of the field and check it [`onValueChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValueChanged.html) like e.g.

```c#
[SerializeField] private InputField _inputField;

private string _lastValue;

private void Awake ()
{
    if(!_inputField) _inputField = GetComponent<InputField>();

    _inputField.onValueChanged += CheckInput;
    _lastValue = _inputField.text;
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    _inputField.onValueChanged -= CheckInput;
}

private char CheckInput()
{
    var lastChar = _lastValue[_lastValue.Length - 1];

    //ToDo Do something with lastChar  
   
    
    // Update the last value
    _lastValue = _inputField.text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But how does this work with the keyboard backspace function? Normally our keyboard backspace - deletes the character from the string. I want that deleted/removed character which gets deleted with the keyboard backspace.

Comment: well I don't exactly know how Unity handles this but .. my first example assumes it is passed as the backspace char `\b` so you can catch an "validate" it in order to read out and store the last char from the current string befire the backspace char is applied. The second char reacts after the value was changed but stores the previous version where the last char was still there and therefore can access and handle it